# Для чего нужен Python?

Tags: python

Как гласит википедия, python - язык общего назначения. Но какие конкретные полноценные задачи можно на нём решать? Игры используют его лишь поверхностно, а какой то пин-понг написанный на нём - работает криво, для вебсайтов он - не лучший вариант. Для чего он и почему же он так популярен, если не из-за решения и упрощения рутиных задач, а не для полноценного программирования?

Comment: "пин-понг написанный на нём - работает криво" Если что-то написано криво оно и будет работать криво.  "html - язык для полнейших нубов"  это думаю без комментариев

Comment: HTML вообще не язык программирования , а язык разметки.А верстальщик — это целая профессия (легкость освоения)

Comment: @sensoid когда Вы задаете вопрос обратите внимание на то как его воспримут окружающие ...

Comment: «Бесконечное лето» вон написано на Python и вполне себе расположилось в Steam, например. Можно и пинг-понг нормальный написать и в стим запихнуть — было бы желание

Comment: Языков не общего назначения не так уж и много и в большинстве своем о них мало кто знает. Большинство конкретных полноценных проблем как раз и решаются на языках общего назначения.

Comment: @sensoid, полное изменение текста вопроса при наличии ответов - вандализм. Вопрос не оскорбителен для участников, а не соответствует правилам сайта. Удалить вопрос естественно не можете, потому что уже есть ответы с положительным рейтингом. Считайте, что вы уже не можете распоряжаться судьбой вопроса.

Comment: @insolortiredofthisdrama сам вопрос - вандализм, теперь бессоницу словлю оттого что у меня появился новый скелет в шкафу

Comment: @sensoid, ну чтож, живите с этим

Answer (score 6):

В основном `Python` используется  в:

- Data Science (наука о данных: их анализ, визуализация)
- Machine learning (машинное обучение и искусственный интеллект)
- Backend Web-разработке (серверные части сайтов, различные `API`)
- Автоматизации

Также его можно встретить в системном программировании (части дистрибутивов `Linux`) и даже в разработке игр и десктопных приложений (например, на `Qt`).

---

> какой то пин-понг написанный на нём - работает криво

Какой-то, может, и криво. Но в чём вина `Python`? Ничего не мешает написать "прямой" пинг-понг на `Python`.

> для вебсайтов он - не лучший вариант, ведь html - язык для полнейших
>   нубов, если вообще язык.

Первое не следует из второго.

`Python` отличный вариант для Web-разработки. Благодаря прекрасным фреймворкам (например, `Django` и `Flask`), на нём очень удобно писать `Backend` (т. е. серверные части сайтов) и различные небольшие `API`.

В подтверждение приведу крупные проекты, бо́льшая часть которых написана именно на `Python`:

1. YouTube
2. Google Search
3. DropBox
4. Instagram
5. Reddit

Comment: eve online, вполне успешный проект, написан на пайтон, по крайне мере был, 5 лет назад

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо за информацию! Я даже не знал об этом, хотя немного играл в `EVE`. Это отличный пример.

Comment: а я раньше плотно в нее залипал, а потом бросил все, так и валяется барахло по всей галактике

Comment: а html, особенно 5 - это плохо понятно что, особенно canvas api, webgl, svg и еще много какого api: вебсокеты, видео, аудио, сенсоры, websql, indexeddb, и многое другое

Comment: «крупные проекты, большая часть» — пять штучек это точно не большая, да и даже актуальность информации об этих пяти штучках под вопросом

Comment: @andreymal Насчёт актуальности согласен. В нашей сфере всё слишком быстро меняется. Я решил привести эти проекты скорее для того, чтобы показать "зрелость" языка и заинтересованность в нём крупных компаний. Но про *"пять штучек это точно не большая,"* не понимаю Вас. Бо́льшая часть этих проектов написана на `Python` (или когда-то была). В чём я не прав?

Answer (score 3):

**пару слов про HTML**

1. BOM является частью общей спецификации HTML.

Да, вы всё верно услышали. Спецификация HTML по адресу https://html.spec.whatwg.org не только про «язык HTML» (теги, атрибуты), она также покрывает целое множество объектов, методов и специфичных для каждого браузера расширений DOM. Это всё «HTML в широком смысле». Для некоторых вещей есть отдельные спецификации, перечисленные на https://spec.whatwg.org. информация взята https://learn.javascript.ru/browser-environment

2. HTML - это язык гипертекстовой разметки;
3. HTML это база для таких языков программирования как JS и PHP (про другие языки программирования не знаю ) по манипулированию web-страницей
4. Если что не так дополняйте и поправляйте не обижусь :))

Answer (score 3):

> Как гласит википедия, python - язык общего назначения.

Все правильно гласит википедия.

> Но какие конкретные полноценные задачи можно на нём решать?

Какие задачи? Да любые. Но результат будет разный. :-)

Python начинался как скриптовой язык (интерпретатор) для встраивания в приложения. Потом на Python обратил внимание большой бизнес в лице Микрософта и начал его продвигать. Сответственно, наделали много библиотек для Python  и еще больше оберток над старыми библиотеками. Так что теперь на Python можно решать почти любые задачи, главное найти работающую библиотеку.

Answer (score 1):

Блин даже не знаю что сказать ежели html для нубов , а пинг понг работает криво черт возьми.
Если что-то работает криво , то потому что надо кодить не криво , а язык тут не причем!
Теперь к делу :
Python — язык общего назначения с богатейшей библиотекой.
На нем можно делать все:
В особенности фронтенд , бэкенд, искусственные нейронные сети, 
GUI все что угодно!

Answer (score 1):

Фреймворк Django как пример. Лучшая безопасность, удобство и много крутых моментов связаных с разработкой.На python можно писать под Android и ПК. Огромное кол-во библиотек помогают решать  большую часть задач быстро тк часто алгоритмы линейны. Проще в понимании, чем Java или C++. Поэтому конкурент ему только JS.